# Rails: Gem that runs bundle install and a list of commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle

I'm creating a gem that runs some commands inside a folder.

List of commands:

```
bundle install
bundle exec rake db:migrate db:seed
```

Commands are un using

```
Dir.chdir folder_name
stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3 command
```

The problem is that the bundle install is run inside the gem and not inside the folder. And running the rake commands returns an error: rails not found because bundle is not run inside the folder.

Any idea?

Comment: You would need to use `Dir.pwd`. And why would you need a gem to run `rake db:prepare`?

Comment: If it is a matter of saving keyboard typing less, why don't you simply create a bash script to run these commands?